# ERROR 1064 (42000) MySQL when inside a shell script

Tags: mysql, ksh

I have shell script with mysql command, there I am getting ERROR 1064 (42000).
MySQL Version (5.5.32)

```
#!/bin/ksh
#ALCO update
#Author:Umani

a=`date`

echo $a

mysql -u root << EOF
use test;
select offer_id,action_date from alco_offer_assign_history where offer_id='307' limit 10;
bye;


echo "Complete"

exit;
```

Sample Output:

```
307 2/20/2014 14:40
307 2/20/2014 14:42
307 2/20/2014 14:42
307 2/20/2014 14:42
```

ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 3: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'bye' at line 1

Comment: I put "bye" to exit from mysql session , used "exit" also. same out put received.  Without 'bye' then getting below error...  ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 6: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'echo "Complete"

exit' at line 1

Answer (score 2):

You should close "EOF" before writing another shell commands and not need to explicit exiting:

```
#!/bin/ksh
#ALCO update
#Author:Umani

a=`date`

echo $a

mysql -u root << EOF
use test;
select offer_id,action_date from alco_offer_assign_history where offer_id='307' limit 10;
EOF

echo "Complete"

exit;
```

Comment: @web-tiki, thanks for commenting. I edited the answer with working example